# How to reorganize data to display how many times a string appears in an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to create four pie charts using Chart.js that displays the number of languages in each category (I - IV) that appear in each region. In other words, I'd like to have one pie chart for Category I that displays how many Category I languages are spoken in each region, another that that displays how many Category II languages are spoken in each region, etc.

My array element looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "category": "1",
    "language": "Danish",
    "weeks": "24",
    "hours": "600",
    "region": "Europe",
    "title": "World",
    "description": "Languages closely cognate with English"
  },
  {
    "category": "1",
    "language": "Dutch",
    "weeks": "24",
    "hours": "600",
    "region": "Europe",
    "title": "World",
    "description": "Languages closely cognate with English"
  },
  {
    "category": "1",
    "language": "French",
    "weeks": "30",
    "hours": "750",
    "region": "Europe",
    "title": "World",
    "description": "Languages closely cognate with English"
  },
```

...and so on. Some languages include more than one region, such as:

```
 {
    "category": "1",
    "language": "Spanish",
    "weeks": "24",
    "hours": "600",
    "region": ["Europe", "South America", "North America"],
    "title": "World",
    "description": "Languages closely cognate with English"
  }
```

I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be. Do I need to create a new array or rearrange my data somehow? Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to create a temporary variable, say `var temp = 0`  which holds first occurrence of a language. If you find this language again under a loop. you should apply `++` operation on it. and at the termination of this loop you may `print` this `temp` variable. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First you filter it by each category, then make an array of language Strings. Then make object that holds each language appearance by counting it.

```js
const categroy1data = data.filter(val => val.category === 1).map(val => val.language);
// => ['Danish', 'Dutch', 'Spanish' ... ]

const category1result = {}
category1data.forEach(val => {
  category1result[val] = 1 + (category1result[val] || 0)
})
// { 
//   Danish: 3,
//   Dutch: 2,
//   Spanih: 1,
// }
```

Comment: It is better to create function for this, since you will need to repeat this for other categories!